# Why isn't it showing Id? It shows Game Object(none) instead of id

Tags: python, html, django, database

so i'm making a site that takes id for different pages for the path 'games/(id)'.
when i make an object in the database table 'games', and pass it to html with context, django knows it exists and doesnt give error on the page. but when i write in the html to show {{game}} it shows Game Object(none) instead of Game Object('insert id here').
and when i do {{game.name}} it shows nothing.
heres the code in 'views.py':

```
def game(request, pk):
    game = Games.objects.get(id=pk)
    context = {'Game':Games}
    return render(request, 'games/games.html', context)
```

i tried different way to do this, but nothing. still shows none.

i've tried different ways with the model, but still nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Context Variables are case sensitive

```
game = Games.objects.get(id=pk)
context = {'Game':Games}
```

The object you fetched has a variable name `game` but in your context you are referencing `Games`. Change that to:

```
game = Games.objects.get(id=pk)
context = {'game': game}
```